# MessageData in RoutingSlip

Tags: masstransit

I am attempting to use MessageData within a routing slip. I am wondering if the automatic handling is implemented here, since I've only been able to get it working by manually using the IMessageDataRepository, and setting MessageDataDefaults.AlwaysWriteToRepository to true and MessageDataDefaults.Threshold to 0.

(some types below may not be the exact names, I'm typing from memory)

Attempting to save an object directly in the message results in it being serialized, and then the next activity failing to deserialize a MessageDataReference.

Attempting to save a PutMessageData in the message results in EmptyMessageDataException when accessed in the next activity.

Attempting to save an object under the size of MessageDataDefaults.Threshold with IMessageDataRepository.PutObject results in InlineBytesMessageData being serialized, and the next activity failing to deserialize it correctly.

Saving a an object above the size of MessageDataDefaults.Threshold saves an object that can be deserilized correctly in the next step. This is what we have ended up doing.

Note that the initial send into the routing slip works as expected, but between activities does not. This seems to be true for both Log and Variables, but I'm not 100% sure on log.

Example that works so long as Ids is larger than threshold:

```cs
    public interface Log
    {
        MessageData<Stream> Ids { get; set; }
    }
    
    public interface Arguments
    {
        List<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class MyActivity : IActivity<Arguments, Log>
    {
        private readonly IMessageDataRepository _messageDataRepository;
        
        public MyActivity(IMessageDataRepository messageDataRepository)
        {
            _messageDataRepository = messageDataRepository;
        }

        public async Task<CompensationResult> Compensate(CompensateContext<Log> context) 
        {
            var ids = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Guid>>(await context.Log.Ids.Value);
            return context.Compensated();
        }
        
        public async Task<ExecutionResult> Execute(ExecuteContext<Arguments> context)
        {
           // It is contrived to get the object from arguments, but anything that produces alot of data
           var messagedata = _messageDataRepository.PutObject(Context.Arguments.Ids, typeof(List<Guid>));

           return context.CompletedWithVariables(
              new { Ids = messagedata },
              new { Ids = messagedata });
        }
    }

    public interface SecondArguments
    {
        MessageData<Stream> Ids { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondActivity: IActivity<SecondArguments>
    {       
        public async Task<ExecutionResult> Execute(ExecuteContext<SecondArguments> context)
        {
           var ids = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Guid>>(await context.Log.Ids.Value);
           return context.Completed();
        }
    }
```

This also seems to hold true for `MessageData<string>` and manually serializing to string. I am using MassTransit 7.2.4.

How should I proceed? Are there things I should do instead?

Comment: MessageData it not supported when using RoutingSlips currently. It's on the long-term maybe do eventually list of features.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer.Well, we have something that works here at least, and will weigh the pros and cons of using it with threshold of 0. Unless you would strongly recommend against this, that is.

Comment: I don't see any downsides, it's manual on your part but you've figured it out so all good.